# Do pixels render the same size in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, pixel

I'm very afraid of browsers rendering differences. So my concerns are all about browsers issues.

I know i can test in different browser, but are a lot to worry about and that stress me.

I have an old laptop I use to work on my CSS projects until I have conditions to buy a more current one. So I cant test in modern browsers.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are afraid will render so differently in newer browsers? What are you so afraid of? Otherwise it's a bit hard to answer this question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Properly built web pages don't need to be concerned with pixels. Use good, [responsive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design) practices and worry less. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], though. Your question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

In general, pixels should render at the same size across all modern browsers, as long as the device pixel ratio (DPR) is the same. However, there can be differences in how browsers handle certain CSS properties or how they interpret certain HTML elements, which can result in visual differences in the layout or appearance of a webpage.

Additionally, if the device pixel ratio (DPR) of the device or screen where the webpage is being viewed is different, it can affect how the webpage is rendered. For example, on a device with a higher DPR, a pixel might appear smaller, resulting in the webpage looking smaller overall.

To minimize the risk of browser rendering differences, it's a good idea to use modern and well-supported CSS and HTML techniques, as well as testing your webpage in multiple browsers and devices to ensure consistent rendering. If you're unable to test on modern browsers due to hardware limitations, consider using online browser testing services or virtual machines to simulate different browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0):

In general, as far as I know. Pixels render the same size in all browsers. keep in mind that some criteria can be taken into consideration. Such as browser default setting or screen resolution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).